# Too many values to unpack (expected 2) in Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-forms

`I want to render the checkbox in the template goals.html, what am i doing wrong here?

Models.py

**The Goal is to capture the input**
**There would be a set of goals and there should be 2 check boxes associated with them**

**The check is for checkboxes**

```
from django.db import models
```

**There would be a set of goals and there should be 2 check boxes associated with them**

```
# Create your models here.
class GoalModel(models.Model):
    Goal=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Check=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Goal
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import GoalModel
from .forms import GoalForm, GoalCheck

# Create your views here.



def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = GoalForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/goals/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = GoalForm

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})


def goals(request):
`this shows all the goals in the db`
    show_goals=GoalModel.objects.all()
    '''
        if request.method == "POST":
            display_type = request.POST.get("display_type", None)
            if display_type in ["Done", "Didn't do"]:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/play/')
    '''

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_check = GoalCheck(request.POST or None)

            # Have Django validate the form for you
        if form_check.is_valid():
                # The "display_type" key is now guaranteed to exist and
                # guaranteed to be "displaybox" or "locationbox"
            display_type = request.POST["display_type"]
            if display_type in ["Done", "Didn't do"]:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/play/')
    else:
        form_check = GoalCheck(request.POST or None)

    # This will display the blank form for a GET request
    # or show the errors on a POSTed form that was invalid
    zipped=list(zip(show_goals, form_check))
    return render(request, 'goals.html', {'show_goals': show_goals,
    'form_check':form_check, 'zipped':zipped})
```

**I'm trying to render GoalCheck i think that's where the error originates from**

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import GoalModel
from django.forms import ModelForm


DISPLAY_CHOICES = [(
        ("DoneBox", "Done is"),
        ("Didn'tDoBox", "Didn't Do is")
    )]

class GoalForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=GoalModel
        fields=['Goal',]


class GoalCheck(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=DISPLAY_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model=GoalModel
        fields=['Goal', 'Check','category']
```

index.html

```
    <center>
    <h2>What do you want to do everyday</h2>


    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </center>
```

goals.html

```
<center>
<h2>What did you do today?</h2>

<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
{% for goals  in show_goals %}
    <p>{{goals}}</p>

    {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

{{form_check.as_p}}
</form>
```

`I tried rendering the checkbox and it gave me this error: Too many values to unpack (expected 2) in Django please what am i doing wring here?`

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do here but you do not need to loop over the form.  You can simply output as:

```
{{ form }}
```

or as

```
{{ form.category }}
```

Also, you seem to want to make one form but you have two form classes.  You should simply use one.